# How do I access google drive api from my app

Tags: android, google-signin, google-drive-android-api

I try to access google drive from my app so for that authentication required. I setup the code in developer console .but when I try to implement GoogleSignInOption  and GoogleSignInClient code it display mail popup which are logged in by my device but when I pressed any one mail it can not proceed further, just only show progressbar,what I do console not show any error too.

My code was :

```
GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new 
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                                       .requestEmail()
                                        .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE)).build();
    GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,signInOptions);
    startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(),REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
```

process is not entered in onActivityResult method ,please let me know what to do for solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a google bug, to fix it you have to set your app status as published in Google Developers Console

Go to the Developers console and click in the Google OAuth Consent Screen part

Then click in Publish app to set your app status as published

[image]

This is needed because of a Google bug you can check it out here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178183308